# Taylor series for $x^w/w$ around $w=1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

Let $x \in \mathbb{C}$. What is the Taylor series for $x^w/w$ around $w=1$?

I have tried by finding the $n$-th derivative of $\frac{x^w}{w}$ with respect to $w$, and then evaluating it at $w=1$. I only have a recurrence relation which doesn’t seem to help much.
$$R_n := \left( \frac{x^w}{w} \right)^{(n)} = R_{n-1} \ln x -\left( \frac{x^w}{w^n} \right)^{(n-1)}$$.

Comment: So you basically refer to $\;w\;$ as the *variable*, and $\;x\;$ is just a constant...?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Taylor series of $\;f(z)=\cfrac{a^z}z\;$ , with more usual symbols, around $\;z=1\;$ , we can do as follows:

$$\frac{a^z}z=\frac1{1+(z-1)}\cdot a\cdot a^{z-1}=a\sum_{n=0}^\infty(z-1)^n\cdot e^{(z-1)\log a}=a\sum_{n=0}^\infty(z-1)^n\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\log^na}{n!}(z-1)^n$$

Continue...and the above is valid for $\;|z-1|<1\;$ (for the part of the geometric series)

Comment: So by Cauchy Product I get $x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{m=0}^n \frac{\ln^{n-m} x}{(n-m)!} \right) (w-1)^n$. Is this correct?

Comment: @palindromicprime Yes, you can do Cauchy product...though in the unit disk $\;|z|<1\;$ it doesn't matter how you do it as both series converge there absolutely.